# How to open View from UIPageViewController and return to back to the UIPageViewController

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm having issues with opening a view from a UIPageViewController and returning back to the same page on the PageViewController. My current setup is a tutorial, you scroll across the pages to view the tutorial. On the second page it requires the user to make a selection of items off a TableView on another page (by clicking a button). How would I then return back to the second page of the UIPageViewController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like this: `controller.setViewControllers([self.pages[page]], direction: .forward, animated: false, completion: nil)`

Direction and animation is up to You.

You can show second vc from page just by using `presentViewController:animated:completion:` from your page. Set up some delegation to pass data between parent controller and presented controller.

After selection You just `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` and You are right back where You are previously.

Comment: Not what I'm looking for... I know how to setup a PageViewController. I'm trying to open another view (not on the page view controller), then return back to the same page as I was on in the pageviewcontroller.

Comment: @NickM - I added simplest solution.